# Is the convergence of $\dot{x}=2A(t)x$ faster than that of $\dot{x}=A(t)x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. If $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ and $\dot{x}=cA(t)x$ with $c>1$ are exponentially stable. Is the convergence rate of $x$ to zero of $\dot{x}=cA(t)x$ faster than that of $\dot{x}=A(t)x$?

Here is my initial thought:

For linear time-invariant system, the fact $\dot{x}=A(t)x$ is exponentially stable implies $A(t)=A$ is Hurwitz. It is clear that the $i$th eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}(cA)=c\lambda_{i}(A)$, $i,\ldots,n$, thus, the convergence for $\dot{x}=cAx$ with $c>1$ is faster than that of $\dot{x}=Ax$.

For a linear time-varying system. Let us consider the extreme case where $c=0$, $\dot{x}=cA(t)x=0$, which implies it is no longer exponentially stable.

For $c>1$, can we have the same conclusion for exponentially stable linear time-varying systems, i.e., can we conclude that the convergence is faster when $c>1$?

Update 1:
For a scalar time-varying system, i.e., $x\in\mathbb{R}$. We can actually prove this conjecture. In fact, from the uniqueness of the equilibrium point ($x=0$ is the only solution that renders $\dot{x}=0$), the solution of $\dot{x}=ca(t)x$ is a monotone function either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, depending on its initial condition $x(0)$. Thus, for $\dot{x}=ca(t)x$ where $c>1$, the absolute value of the derivative is larger than that of $\dot{x}=a(t)x$, while for both cases the sign of $\dot{x}(t)$ remains unchanged for all $t\ge0$. Thus, $\dot{x}=ca(t)x$ does converge faster to $x=0$ than $\dot{x}=a(t)x$.

Comment: I still doubt there might be counterexamples for the time-varying case.

Comment: But wait, say if $c\lambda_i(A) > 1$ given that $\lambda_(A) < 1$. Then it might be not stable at all, right?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added both systems are assumed to be stable. I have edited the question.

Comment: This is a continuous-time system. For the time-invariant case, if $A$ is Hurwitz, then $cA$ is Hurwitz for any positive $c$.

Comment: I think this might be false in general case. Sorry my brevity (I’m on my phone). Solving this ODE for general $A(t)$ needs an integration of matrix-function $A(\cdot)$, which may lead to a matrix, which, in turn,  may not yield a stable system, letting alone the convergence rates.

Comment: It is assumed that the system $\dot{x}=cA(t)x$ with $c\ge1$ is exponentially stable. The convergence of the solution $x(t)$ to zero as $t$ tends to $\infty$ is guaranteed.

Comment: @pointguard0 In general, solving such an ODE requires much more complicated formula than simple integration of $A(\cdot)$, see [Peano-Baker series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano-Baker_series)

Comment: The systems $\dot x=cA(t)x$, where $A(t)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} -9\,{\cos^2\left(6t\right)}+6\,\sin\left(12t\right)-1 & 12\,{\cos^2\left(6t\right)}+9\,\sin\left(6t\right)\,\cos\left(6t\right)\\ 9\,\cos\left(6t\right)\,\sin\left(6t\right)-12\,{\sin^2\left(6t\right)} & -9\,{\sin^2\left(6t\right)}-12\,\cos\left(6t\right)\,\sin\left(6t\right)-1 \end{array}\right)$, where $c\in (0,0.55)$ appears to be the counterexample. However, I do not have a proof...

Comment: It may be interesting that for nonlinear stationary systems $\dot x=f(x)$ the conjecture is true

Comment: I think for time-invariant nonlinear system $\dot{x}=f(x)$, by linearization, near its equilibrium point $x=0$, this conjecture is true locally because the linearized system is reduced to a stable linear time-invariant system $\dot{x}=Ax$, where $A$ is Hurwitz.